# Проблема с установкой MySQL

Tags: mysql

Хочу установить MySQL. Всё идёт хорошо до тех пор, пока не начинается процесс конфигурирования сервера. На этапе Starting server всё время выскакивает следующее сообщение:

> Configuration of MySQL Server  is taking longer than expected. Do you
>   want to continue waiting or cancel the configuration? If you keep
>   waiting you may get this message again.

Я закрываю его, через некоторое время оно появляется вновь.
И так бесконечное количество раз. И переустанавливал несколько раз, и через реестр удалять пробовал, и разные версии качал - всё как об стенку горох! Подскажите, как мне быть?

Comment: Вы не написали по какой операционкой это происходит.

Comment: Windows 10, 64x

Answer (score 1):

Есть упоминания, что данная проблема может возникать если стартовать 32-бит дистрибутив на 64-бит Windows. Надо скачать соответствующий инсталятор.

Другая возможная причина — почему-то в свойствах Сервиса MySQL прописывается старт из-под неверного аккаунта. Посмотреть и исправить вручную, если надо. Должно быть так: Вход в систему / "С системной учетной записью" и выключена галочка на "Взаимодействие с рабочим столом".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server